# Geography data type and Upgrading from 2008 r2 to SQLServer 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014, upgrade, spatial

I am getting a warning about a data type called `geography`.

Our system has 1 column of data type `geography`. I am trying to figure out if the upgrade will fail or just if an app may have an issue.

[Warning about client side usage of `GEOMETRY, GEOGRAPHY and HIERARCHYID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn236441(v=sql.120).aspx)

Anybody have an idea? Under Importance of error there is red ball with an X through it, so I assume the upgrade will fail. Is that correct? It says to fix before. I notice SQL Server 2014 has the `geography` type still, so I do not know what to think.

From export to csv it shows this:

> Database Server
>   PreUpgrade
>   Warning about client side usage of `GEOMETRY, GEOGRAPHY and HIERARCHYID`
>   Upgrade Advisor detected usage SQL CLR Types
>   Database: Metrics
>   Column Name: Location

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade should not fail (For this reason anyway).  As stated in the link you provided, this is an application issue and only if it is directly accessing the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll.

The upgrade from 2008r2 to 2014 should work fine.